# Nginx: After removing .html suffixes, how to redirect all requests to the new URLs?

Tags: nginx, regex, 301-redirect, rewritecond

I want to optimize the link structure of an older Magento shop system. Until now, when generating the static pages, a .html suffix was added to the corresponding path. Due to an earlier problem, paths with double suffixes even existed (e.g. .html.html). Now that I have disabled the use of suffixes and deleted all paths with double suffixes from the database, I want to set up automatic redirections from the old URLs to the new ones.

To preserve existing hyperlinks and search engine entries, I want Nginx to redirect all requests for pages with a .html or .html.html suffix to the new path.

Requests to:

```
example.org/banana.html
example.org/banana.html.html
```

should be redirected to:

```
example.org/banana
```

so actual my best guess is:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*?)\.html(\.html)?$ $1 permanent;
  try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.html.html $uri/ =404;
}
```

How do I reach my goal and what rewrite rules do I need to add to the nginx configuration?

Comment: The two `try_files` statements should be combined into a single statement, for example: `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.html.html $uri/ =404;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! Are the rewrites a good solution to preserve the existing links to my site or are there other methods that are even more SEO friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use one `try_files` statement inside a `location` block. The *file* terms can be added as required. Include a `$uri` term to match those URIs which directly match static files (e.g. `.css` and `.js`). Include a `$uri/` term if you want to use the `index` directive.

For example:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.html.html $uri/ =404;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

---

The `rewrite` statements are the wrong way around as the first one will always match a URI intended for the second one. Also, the rewrites are capturing a leading `/` in `$1` variable, so by using `/$1` you are adding an extra leading `/`.

You can also combine both regular expressions into a single statement, for example:

```
rewrite ^(.*?)\.html(\.html)?$ $1 permanent;
```